# I could have GCC 4.6.2 working within Xcode 4.2 if it wasn't for this CFString nonsense

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, gcc, xcode4

I compiled GCC 4.6.2 on Mac OS X 10.6 since Xcode 4.2 doesn't come with GCC. I haven't gotten it fully working yet inside Xcode because Xcode insists on passing the -fconstant-cfstrings parameter to GCC and I can't seem to disable it. I've edited out most of the Apple specific stuff in my custom .xcplugin, but the -fconstant-cfstrings option is nowhere to be found so I can't remove it! Furthermore, using @ to create a string literal doesn't work properly (strings don't seem to be allocated correctly). The workaround is to use the CFSTR() macro, and cast it to NSString* to avoid compiler warnings.

What I would like to do is figure out a way to leave all my @"" strings in the code without having to replace them with CFSTR(). The GCC documentation talks about a header file in  that may be responsible for doing this, but I'm afraid it is being overridden by CFString.h. If anyone has any idea of how to fix this, I'd really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

Xcode is very hard to get working with non-Apple approved compilers. It *should* come with GCC 4.2.1 LLVM-GCC as well as Clang 3.0. Is there any specific reason you need 4.6.2 (or a compiler other than the default clang)?

Comment: All I've read gives the performance edge to GCC, plus I like to keep my scripts / makefiles consistent across platforms without having to use Apple-specific options. And frankly, I've spent so much time on it already I can't just quit now! :-D

Comment: In that case, I'd recommend just not using Xcode. I'm talking from experience: I tried to do exactly the same thing as you but I wasn't able to get it to work. In the end, I was editing files in Xcode but `make`ing them in Terminal.

The problem is how integrated the apple tools are. It's fantastic if you want to do Objective-C programming (seriously), and horrible if you try to do anything else.

Comment: That's what I'm doing now. How did you overcome the -fconstant-cfstrings issue?

Comment: Hahaha I just tried to recreate your problem, using my copy of gcc 4.6(.2). I can't even get to that--my compiler is still complaining at Obj-C syntax. I didn't know you wanted to work with Obj-C (I missed the Cocoa tag on your question). As much as general code generation is better in GCC, Apple's Clang/LLVM-GCC have highly optimized `objc_msgSend` routines. On a side note, might this document help you out? http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.4/gcc/Constant-string-objects.html#Constant-string-objects

Comment: Yeah, I read that but I think Apple's headers (CFString.h?) are overriding this. I tried including it in my Objective-C header, but it didn't make any difference. I was able to get GCC to compile Obj-C just fine, and used ibtool to compile XIBs. Everything works OK, it's just that I need to use that CFSTR() macro (defined in CFString.h) every time I need to create a string literal. Passing the -fconstant-cfstrings switch enables a __ builtin __ which I think is specific to Apple's GCC 4.2. You can see what I'm talking about in CFString.h. I also can't use old code that has a lot of @"".

Comment: That is really annoying... maybe you (or someone else) could whip up a quick regex replace script that will change @"..." to CFSTR(...)? Then you could put that in your makefile before compiling.